# CSS Picture fit by smallest dimension

Tags: css

I am wondering, is it possible to declare some agile CSS rule for sizing pictures in a frame so I get most of them if I want to just see part of them. 
Example: I have a div with dimensions 10em/10em and I get pictures with various aspect ratio. 
What I want is this:
If picture has Width 15 and height 40. =>
    `img{width:100% height: auto;}`

If picture has Height 15 and width 40. =>
    `img{height:100%; width:auto;}`
Idea is pictures to not be restricted of specific aspect ratio, I am aware I will not see the whole picture but just trimmed part of it, /overflow-hidden/. 
I also don't want to shrink pictures to make them fit.
If I config one of the rules they work for half of the cases.

Comment: Try to play with [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), may be it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thank you object-fit: contain; is what I needed.